# "זֶה ... וְזֶה" referring to the same or different entities

Tags: hebrew, grammar

The construction זֶה ... וְזֶה can indicate both "one ... the other ..." and "this one ... this one", so the entity that the two זֶהs refer to can be the same or different. This is shown by Song 5:16 (the same entity) vs. Ps 75:8 (different entities), for instance:

> [Song 5:16](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/sng/5/16/t_conc_676016):
> **זֶה** דֹודִי **וְזֶה** רֵעִי בְּנֹות יְרוּשָׁלִָֽם
> **This** is my beloved and **this** is my friend, O daughters of Jerusalem. (ESV)
>
> [Ps 75:8](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/psa/75/8/t_conc_553007):
> כִּֽי־אֱלֹהִים שֹׁפֵט **זֶה** יַשְׁפִּיל **וְזֶה** יָרִֽים
> but it is God who executes judgment, putting down **one** and lifting up **another**. (ESV)

Are there any syntactical/grammatical reasons for the difference in meaning, or is this purely contextual?

Other occurrences of interest would be 1 Kgs 22:20 || 2 Chr 18:19; 1 Chr 22:1; Isa 44:5 and Job 1:16,17,18.

Comment: Wouldn't 'this one' work for all cases (context-driven adjustments allowed for and taken into consideration)?

Comment: @SolaGratia yes, I'm not concerned with meaning or translation possibilities. From context it's quite clear what is meant. I'm just wondering if there is something in the syntactic structure that I'm missing that signifies the difference as well.

Comment: I see. My two cents (as someone who knows next to no Hebrew): I believe whether or not זה means 'this one' or 'this other one/another [as opposed to this first one]' is purely dependant upon whether the prefixed ו is itself taken to be adversative or not ('but,' 'whereas' etc. [e.g. 1 Chr 22:1] vs. 'and'/a colon, etc. [e.g. Ex 3:15; Songs 5:16]). Which of course is driven by the context (such as here, where two opposites sandwich וזה, yield an adversative ו—"and this *other* .. [a different fate]").

Answer (score 1):

The "algorithm" for differentiation is as follows.

When two or more *zeh*s (זה וזה or זאת וזה) refer to the **same thing**, they are the subjects of the implied verb "to be" and neither is the subject of an explicit verb.

When two or more *zeh* refer to **different things**, they are each the subjects or objects of one or more explicit verbs.

The exceptions are as follows.

I Chron 22:1 (different and not related) וַיֹּאמֶר דָּוִיד **זֶה** הוּא בֵּית יְהוָה הָאֱלֹהִים **וְזֶה**-מִּזְבֵּחַ לְעֹלָה לְיִשְׂרָאֵל

This verse, like most of Chronicles is written in a later, less literary form of Hebrew that, like modern Hebrew, does not respect the *zeh...w'zeh* parallel form as a literary construct. The *zeh*s in this verse are simply the subjects of two consecutive unrelated clauses that are combined in a single verse.

Isaiah 38:7 looks like it might fit, but in fact does not fit the *zeh w'zeh* construct: **וְזֶה**-לְּךָ הָאוֹת מֵאֵת יְהוָה אֲשֶׁר יַעֲשֶׂה יְהוָה אֶת-הַדָּבָר **הַזֶּה** אֲשֶׁר דִּבֵּר There are many other similar verses that do not quite fit the construct.

Isaiah 6:3 uses *zeh el zeh*, a similar construction to *zeh..w'zeh*, to indicate multiple individuals calling out to each other: וְקָרָא **זֶה** **אֶל-זֶה** וְאָמַר קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ יְהוָה צְבָאוֹת מְלֹא כָל-הָאָרֶץ כְּבוֹדוֹ

The examples are as follows.

Same

1. Genesis 28:18 (three, same, implied verb "to be") וַיִּירָא וַיֹּאמַר מַה-נּוֹרָא הַמָּקוֹם **הַזֶּה** אֵין **זֶה** כִּי אִם-בֵּית אֱלֹהִים **וְזֶה** שַׁעַר הַשָּׁמָיִם
2. Exodus 3:15 (same, implied verb "to be")וַיֹּאמֶר עוֹד אֱלֹהִים אֶל-מֹשֶׁה כֹּה תֹאמַר אֶל-בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵי אֲבֹתֵיכֶם אֱלֹהֵי אַבְרָהָם אֱלֹהֵי יִצְחָק וֵאלֹהֵי יַעֲקֹב שְׁלָחַנִי אֲלֵיכֶם **זֶה**-שְּׁמִי לְעֹלָם **וְזֶה** זִכְרִי לְדֹר דֹּר
3. Isaiah 14:26 (same, *zot..w'zot*) **זֹאת** הָעֵצָה הַיְּעוּצָה עַל-כָּל-הָאָרֶץ **וְזֹאת** הַיָּד הַנְּטוּיָה עַל-כָּל-הַגּוֹיִם
4. Isaiah 27:9 (same, *b'zot...w'zeh*) לָכֵן **בְּזֹאת** יְכֻפַּר עֲוֹן-יַעֲקֹב **וְזֶה** כָּל-פְּרִי הָסִר חַטָּאתוֹ בְּשׂוּמוֹ כָּל-אַבְנֵי מִזְבֵּחַ כְּאַבְנֵי-גִר מְנֻפָּצוֹת לֹא-יָקֻמוּ אֲשֵׁרִים וְחַמָּנִים
5. Isaiah 28:12 (same, *zot..w'zot*) אֲשֶׁר אָמַר אֲלֵיהֶם **זֹאת** הַמְּנוּחָה הָנִיחוּ לֶעָיֵף **וְזֹאת** הַמַּרְגֵּעָה וְלֹא אָבוּא שְׁמוֹעַ
6. Song 5:16 (same, implied verb "to be") חִכּוֹ מַמְתַקִּים וְכֻלּוֹ מַחֲמַדִּים **זֶה** דוֹדִי **וְזֶה** רֵעִי בְּנוֹת יְרוּשָׁלִָם
7. Ruth 4:7 (same, *w'zot..w'zot*) **וְזֹאת** לְפָנִים בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל עַל-הַגְּאוּלָּה וְעַל-הַתְּמוּרָה לְקַיֵּם כָּל-דָּבָר שָׁלַף אִישׁ נַעֲלוֹ וְנָתַן לְרֵעֵהוּ **וְזֹאת** הַתְּעוּדָה בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל

Different

1. I Kings 22:20 (different, two explicit verbs)וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה מִי יְפַתֶּה אֶת-אַחְאָב וְיַעַל וְיִפֹּל בְּרָמֹת גִּלְעָד וַיֹּאמֶר **זֶה** בְּכֹה **וְזֶה** אֹמֵר בְּכֹה
2. Isaiah 44:5 (three, different, three different explicit verbs) **זֶה** יֹאמַר לַיהוָה אָנִי **וְזֶה** יִקְרָא בְשֵׁם-יַעֲקֹב **וְזֶה** יִכְתֹּב יָדוֹ לַיהוָה וּבְשֵׁם יִשְׂרָאֵל יְכַנֶּה
3. Psalms 75:8 (different, two different explicit verbs) כִּי-אֱלֹהִים שֹׁפֵט **זֶה** יַשְׁפִּיל **וְזֶה** יָרִים
4. Job 1:16 (different, two different explicit) עוֹד **זֶה** מְדַבֵּר **וְזֶה** בָּא וַיֹּאמַר אֵשׁ אֱלֹהִים נָפְלָה מִן-הַשָּׁמַיִם וַתִּבְעַר בַּצֹּאן וּבַנְּעָרִים וַתֹּאכְלֵם וָאִמָּלְטָה רַק-אֲנִי לְבַדִּי לְהַגִּיד לָךְ
5. Job 1:17 (different, two different explicit verbs) עוֹד **זֶה** מְדַבֵּר **וְזֶה** בָּא וַיֹּאמַר כַּשְׂדִּים שָׂמוּ שְׁלֹשָׁה רָאשִׁים וַיִּפְשְׁטוּ עַל-הַגְּמַלִּים וַיִּקָּחוּם וְאֶת-הַנְּעָרִים הִכּוּ לְפִי-חָרֶב וָאִמָּלְטָה רַק-אֲנִי לְבַדִּי לְהַגִּיד לָךְ
6. Job 1:18 (different, two different explicit verbs) עַד **זֶה** מְדַבֵּר **וְזֶה** בָּא וַיֹּאמַר בָּנֶיךָ וּבְנוֹתֶיךָ אֹכְלִים וְשֹׁתִים יַיִן בְּבֵית אֲחִיהֶם הַבְּכוֹר
7. II Chron 18:19 (different, one explicit verb used twice)וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה מִי יְפַתֶּה אֶת-אַחְאָב מֶלֶךְ-יִשְׂרָאֵל וְיַעַל וְיִפֹּל בְּרָמוֹת גִּלְעָד וַיֹּאמֶר **זֶה** אֹמֵר כָּכָה **וְזֶה** אֹמֵר כָּכָה

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting, but I'm also sceptical. I see the linguistic reasons for a case with different verbs meaning different entities (otherwise the second זֶה is overly heavy). But I'm not sure about the other part, that when [to be] is presupposed the entities must be the same. In English it would be possible to say "This is my father and this is my mother", when accompanied by gestures. And since evidence is rather scarce I'm reluctant to go with such a strong division between the two uses (we may be missing data due to historical accident). Do you have references for the 2nd part?

Comment: @Keelan "sceptical"? I covered **all** of the instances in the OT AFAIK. What more could there be? I don't see any counter-example in the OT.

Comment: That you covered all instances in the HB and the rule is not contradicted there does not mean it is a rule of the grammar. We may miss data which does contradict it, because it has been lost (= historical accident). So I would like to see some linguistic / comparative argument / reference.

Comment: @Keelan Grammar is not relevant here. There is no rule. The question is only about the prevailing manner of usage of a literary construct, zeh w'zeh, or zot w'zeh, or zot w'zot, or zeh w'zot, not grammar. Linguistic, comparative references to what? Cognate languages? A different historical period of Hebrew or Aramaic? Hebrew has several similar figurative expressions, like "each one more beautiful than the other".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you suggest that *all* instances where both זֶהs are subject of the implicit verb "to be" *must* be understood as referring to the same entity twice. It is clear that this holds for the attested instances. What is not clear is whether this rule generalises to the actual living language of which the corpus that has been handed down is only a shadow. To make a claim about the grammar of that language (the meaning of demonstrative pronouns) it is indeed necessary to compare to cognates or different stages, especially in a case like this with little evidence.